# Can you check into a hotel room under someone else's name?

Tags: usa, hotels

I was planning on going on a trip with a friend and booked a room in the hotel under the assumption that we'd be sharing the room. But now it looks like I won't be able to go on the trip.

Can they still use my room reservation even though it's in my name and not their name?

Comment: I'd contact the hotel and tell them someone else will be using the reservation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I would assume so. If you and your friend are listed on your booking then it should be fine, just say you will be checking in instead.

Else, you would want to email/contact the hotel beforehand so the hotel can verify you're not checking in for another person that you don't know.